# Prism5 + Unity, how to raise popup after shell and all modules loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I have issue: popup with injected services should be raised after moment when shell loaded, its something like login form, so i raise it on "Loaded" event on shell.

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
    <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnShellLoadedCommand}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

It happens after CreateShell() in Bootstrapper

```
 protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
 {
     return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
 }
```

With prism`s services all right, but problem occured with shared services, because modules load after CreateShell() and i get exception. What is the good plactise how to raise popup after shell loaded?

Comment: What do you mean by "shared services"?  ConfigureContainer is called before CreateShell, so all of Prism's services should be ready to go when the Shell is loaded.

Comment: Also, are you sure the exception is not being thrown from the "OnShellLoadedCommand" callback?

Comment: Are the services you are trying to use exist in a difference module than the shell, and you are trying to call those services before the modules has loaded?

Comment: @BrianLagunas by "shared services" i mean custom services, i mean services like in your course on pluralsight "Introduction to PRISM"."Communication" theme. Yes, services exist in difference module than the shell and i trying to call those before IModule.Initialize(). If i am right order is 1)ConfigureContainer 2)CreateShell 3)Shell loaded event raised 4)PopupRequest.Raise call in OnShellLoadedCommand 5)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<PopupViewModel> 6)Than occured exception if i try inject sharedService, but all right if i try inject IEventAggregator for example 7)Initialize() on modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rethink how you are showing your login screen.  If your service exists in a module, obviously you can't create and use it until it has been loaded and registered with the container.  So you have a couple of options.  Move your login popup into a view in your module, and place the trigger on that view that you use RegisterViewWithRegion in the IModule show/initialize.  Then use that view's loaded event.  I would actually showing your login dialog before the shell is actually shown.  If the login is successful, show the Shell, if it fails you can close the app.  Either way, you cannot use a service that hasn't been loaded.  So move your login popup to the module that contains the service, or move you login service into the shell so it can be used when the shell is loaded.